# I have a Ford Fusion SE 2010 6 speaker and am trying to wire a small subwoofer with a built in amp

Tags: ford, audio, fusion

Where should I connect my speaker wires, since I don’t have them and rear deck speakers. How do I open the door to get the wires in the door, and where do I connect my remote wire. I am suck at electronics if anyone can help, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do the subwoofer instructions say to connect it to wires in the door? Is there an option to connect the subwoofer directly to the sound system instead of taking the door apart?